# How do I embed ttml caption files inside mp4 video files?

Tags: linux, video, android, mp4, subtitles

In this situation, I know ffmpeg is the general answer by doing something like

```
ffmpeg -i 40\ Days\ Falling\ Apart-55db1e546b66d1421b2cb43c.mp4 -i 40\ Days\ Falling\ Apart-55db1e546b66d1421b2cb43c.en.ttml -c copy -c:s mov_text 40\ Days\ Falling\ Apart.mp4
```

But in my case the titles are in the ttml format which ffmpeg doesn t support.

I can t upload the file to web services because of licensing issues.

Comment: Have you tried the PotPlayer for Android? https://potplayer.en.softonic.com/android

Comment: @vssher I m not interested in playing the video but to merge the caption file into the existing mp4 file.

Comment: By "merge", do you mean burn-in?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I m meaning to put the caption inside the video file. In order to have just one file for everything (video audio and caption).

Comment: Can you indicate in your question how you would've done it with ffmpeg in case it was an srt file? Because in that case it would boil down to `How can I convert a TTML caption file to SRT without using an online converter?`

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke No. Because of the original format being a loose text file, the conversion is changing title duration. Which means means ffmpeg would refuse to merge the mp4 with the reason that duration differs from the video (by one or 2 frames). Instead of putting an xyz problem, I thought it would be better to stick with the original problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what `loose text file` means, but from your comment I understand that you've tried TTML to SRT conversion already without succes? If so, could you please mention that in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111382/discussion-between-saaru-lindestokke-and-user2284570).

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I meanning without almost metadata. An srt files being more rich, things are reconstructed using wrong guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any TTML or MP4 files at hand to test it, so this is an incomplete answer, but the general steps would be:

## 1. Convert the TTML subtitle file to SRT

There are plenty of [online converters](https://gotranscript.com/subtitle-converter) available, but you indicate you need to do it offline.
This [netflix-to-srt repository](https://github.com/isaacbernat/netflix-to-srt) has a script that can convert `.xml` to `.srt`. As TTML files seem to be a type of XML file, you can try the following:

1. Copy the TTML file and change the extension to `.xml`.
2. Clone/download the [netflix-to-srt repository](https://github.com/isaacbernat/netflix-to-srt)
3. [Follow the conversion steps](https://github.com/isaacbernat/netflix-to-srt#convert-them-into-srt) with the XML file from step 1

## 2. Add the subtitles to the video

[This answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289845/1256347) explains how to add subtitles as a separate stream to an MP4 file. With the right video player you can then toggle the subtitles.
[This answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13125122/1256347) explains how you can burn-in the subtitles into the MP4 file. The subtitles will always be visible, regardless of video player and cannot be turned off.